# x86 ax register getting a different value?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I want to compare ax to  5, if the value is greater than 5 it will show an error box. If not it will just print the number. But it always show that the value is greater than 5 even if I input 1. Where does the problem came from?

```
.386 
.model flat,stdcall 
option casemap:none 

include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data 
msg db "Enter Number", 0
msg1 db "The value is too large", 0

.data? 
input db 150 dup(?)
output db 150 dup(?)
.code 


start: 
push offset msg
call StdOut 

push 100
push offset input
call StdIn

lea ax, input
cmp ax, 5
jg Toolarge


exit:
    push 0
    call ExitProcess 

 Toolarge:
     push offset msg1
     call StdOut
     jmp start

end start
```

Comment: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

Answer (score 1):

MASM32 is shipped with an help file: `\masm32\help\masmlib.chm`. It says:

> StdIn receives **text** input from the console and places it in the buffer
>   required as a parameter. The function terminates when Enter is
>   pressed.

I marked the relevant word "text". So, you'll get an ASCII string, not a number suitable for `AX`. You have first to convert it to an "integer" before you can compare it with `cmp`. You can use the MASM32 function `atol`:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include c:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
    msg db "Enter Number", 0
    msg1 db "The value is too large", 0

.data?
    input db 150 dup(?)
    output db 150 dup(?)
.code

start:

    push offset msg
    call StdOut

    push 100
    push offset input
    call StdIn

    push offset input
    call atol

    cmp eax, 5
    jg Toolarge

exit:

    push 0
    call ExitProcess

Toolarge:

    push offset msg1
    call StdOut
    jmp start

end start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
mov ax, input
```

instead of

```
lea ax, input
```

Lea loads a pointer to the item you're addressing (something like 0x12345678) whereas mov loads the actual value at that address.

Comment: It says invalid instruction operands. I think you cannot use mov in moving data from a variable to register.

Comment: `mov ax, word ptr [input]` .. of course you can. It still doesn't make sense, as your whole code, because it's highly likely that the input is ASCII string, not a number, so you would have to compare only first character against ASCII code of digits, like `cmp al,'5'`, but whatever, using `lea` just shows you should rather read some book/tutorials first. Also you should use debugger to watch what is truly happening. (and in assembler there are no true "variables" like in high level languages, it's just memory, addressable by bytes... MASM will give you some notion of "variables", but meh..)